# Is sitting on a double-decker bus's upper deck more hazardous than sitting on its lower deck?

Tags: automotive-engineering

Many people online allege feeling more 'wobbly' or 'unstable' while seated on the upper deck, than on the lower, and that in an accident, sitters on upper floors are more likely to be ejected out through the windshield even if they're wearing seat belts. Are these allegations true?

> [Now I no longer sit in the front top seats,apparently and not surprisingly the most dangerous seating position in a double decker bus crash.](https://www.quora.com/Are-double-decker-buses-safe/answer/Don-Scult)

Quora distinguishes the physics of the upper deck from lower deck.

[Accordingly, the upper deck undergoes more lateral movement and so people standing upstairs are more likely to be thrown sideways.](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-it-dangerous-to-stand-in-the-upper-deck-of-a-double-decker-bus/answer/Jonathan-Gurney-1)

[The upper deck of bus,in comparison to lower, is high. Due to this fact the torque produced in upper deck is larger than the lower one. One standing in upper deck frequently experiences great push and pulls during acceleration and breaking. One can get injured. So, in fact travelling in upper deck of the bus is dangerous.](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-it-dangerous-to-stand-in-the-upper-deck-of-a-double-decker-bus/answer/Manish-Chaulagain-2)

[Many bus operators do not permit standing on the top deck because standing raises the centre of gravity and the force is applied further from the fulcrum.](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-dangers-of-a-double-decker-bus-when-it-comes-to-stability/answer/Alan-Egan)

Comment: So why did you not ask on Quora?

Comment: Risk is higher on the upper deck of hitting a low bridge...

Comment: Yes, because you can look down women's blouses from that height and get sued for sexual harassment. It's a crazy world out there.

Comment: Bwahahaha @william that's hilarious 